# I am trying to do a while loop with a string conditional statement in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I can not get rid of the error and I don't really understand what is happening.

My code look like this and I always have the same error message:

error message : 'A local or parameter named 'test' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter'

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string test = String.Empty;

        while (!test[1].Equals('r'))
        {
            var privateKey = new Key(); // generate a random private key
            var publicKey = privateKey.PubKey;
            var Address_testnet = publicKey.GetAddress(Network.TestNet);
            string test = Convert.ToString(Address_testnet); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("public address is {0}", test);

    }
```

Comment: The error message could not be any clearer. Remove the word String inside the while

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string test = "";

        while (!test[1].Equals('r'))
        {
            var privateKey = new Key(); // generate a random private key
            var publicKey = privateKey.PubKey;
            var Address_testnet = publicKey.GetAddress(Network.TestNet);
            test = Convert.ToString(Address_testnet); 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("public address is {0}", test);

    }
```

Comment: test is an empty string, if you retrieve test[1], it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You have already declared `test` variable out of `while` that is why compiler shows you this warning. Some statements such as `for`, `while`, `if`, etc. have own scope of visibility. You can read and fill outer variables, but the outer code cannot use variables which declared inside these statements.

You can read this article to to get more understanding: [Variable and Method Scope in Microsoft .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have already created a test variable outside the loop, and you're trying to create the same variable inside the loop. Try doing this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //here you wanna declare test as " r"
    string test = " r";

    while (!test[1].Equals('r'))
    {
        var privateKey = new Key(); // generate a random private key
        var publicKey = privateKey.PubKey;
        var Address_testnet = publicKey.GetAddress(Network.TestNet);
        //Remove "string" keyword in front of test
        test = Convert.ToString(Address_testnet); 
    }
    Console.WriteLine("public address is {0}", test);

}
```

Comment: Thanks to the quick answer and after taking notice of what you said I have tried :
 But now I have an error like this :'Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)'

Comment: @RomainGT When you declare `test` variable, you're assigning `test` string value to `string.Empty`. It means `test` string doesn't have any characters, it means `1` is invalid index.